# For Loop and While Loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

Can anyone please convert this while loop to for loop.
I will really appreciate it.

```
  var index = 0;
  while (true)
    log(index++);
```

Comment: Just follow [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for). It's an inifinite loop, why would you need that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple implementation:

```js
var index = 0
for (;;)
  log(index++)
```

Comment: @Doe Please mark this question as the accepted answer if it has satisfied your requirements.

Comment: @RichieBendall how do I do that please?

Comment: @Doe Click the grey checkmark next to my answer, underneath the upvote/downvote buttons.

Comment: it's done. You can check now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = true;

for (var index = 0; x == true) {
 log(index++)
}
//if x is never set to false you could very quickly suffer a memory leak
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful